# Button icons missing after ClickOnce deployment

Tags: wpf, image, icons, clickonce

I added icons to my buttons in my `WPF ClickOnce app` but they are missing after deployment.  They show up fine in debug in `Visual Studio 2012`. The icons are set as follows:

> Build Action: Content
>
> Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

This is following another post I saw that says to do this to use them in the following way in `XAML`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Command="{Binding PullForwardCommand}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Icons/pullfwd.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Pull Forward" Style="{StaticResource MenuTB}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I did see all the icons are shown in a folder `Resources/Icon`s (as named in my project) where the app is published (albeit as `forward.png.deploy`).

How do i get the icons to show up in the deployed app?

Comment: Were there errors/warnings reported when the deployment was created? Related question: Are you using the deployment wizard ('Publish' button) in Visual Studio?

Comment: Resources in WPF should have their Build Action set to `Resource`, not `Content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Icon properties to

**Build Action : Resource**

**Copy to Output Directory : Do not Copy**

Hope this should work

Comment: I tried this, still no icons when i deploy the app!  And after setting the png icons to 'Resource' an 'Do not copy', they do not show up when i debug any longer now.  Should i be referencing them in a different way than the OP XAML (<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Icons/pullfwd.png" />)?

Comment: Try <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Icons/pullfwd.png" /> along with the above changes.

Comment: In most of my applications I have used the absolute path as below <Image Source="/Icons/pullfwd.png" /> along with the above mentioned settings. Let me know if problem still persists

Comment: The only way i can get them to show after deployment is to put in the absolute path:  <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/email.png" /> (The Icons folder is in a Resources folder)  So what is the purpose of the pack://siteoforigin stuff?